# FindControl in DetailsView Not working?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, detailsview

I have a Gridview and when the edit button is clicked the details of that row is displayed using a detailsview.

While displaying, I need to find a control in detailsView, and then bind it with a Datasource.

First of All I'm not sure about the event to be used but have used DetailsView1_DataBound. However, if I have to find the control using

```
var control=(ControlType)DetailsView1.Findcontrol("ID");
```

Always returns null. May be I am not using the right event, and it couldn't find the control at that point. Any ideas about the event to be used, and the right code please?

Thanks

Comment: show your Details View Designer code.

Comment: show your aspx and code behind code

Comment: its quite big., which part you want to see

Comment: My Gridview in a update panel and have AsyncPostBackTrigger controlId="DetailsView" for Iteminserted and itemUpdated.

Comment: kundur; did you try my solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `databound event`, you need to take care your `DetailsView Mode`

```
 if (DetailsView1.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit)
    {
      //Put here if you want to find control of your Edit Mode
      var control=(ControlType)DetailsView1.Findcontrol("EditTemplateControlID");
    }

 if (DetailsView1.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Insert)
    {
        //Put here if you want to find control of your Insert Mode
      var control=(ControlType)DetailsView1.Findcontrol("InsertTemplateControlID");
    }
```

Comment: Akthar., Thanks yes i tried it and found the control an binded it., Can I discuss some thing with you., the website is already done and i am just adding a new feature., so what they have done is they took a gridview but they dint specify command buttons of gridview., they took linkbuttons(EDIT AND DELETE). Then in the click event they have displayed the details view., 'I added a gridview in this details view' With your solution I could bind it but cannot see the data.why?????

Comment: you can post it new question; explain your problem in details and post your code behind and form Design; I will definitely help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the answer of Muhammad Akhtar did not help me. The problem was solved after changing the default mode of the DetailsView from 'edit' to 'insert'.

I would also recommend the ItemCreated event instead of the DataBound event. I use it often for setting a default value in a field of the DetailsView.